# Entity Framework updates model that is not given

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm trying to update only selected rows of a grid box. But when I click update button, rows that are in that grid update, even if I send only one model to update function. What am I missing here?

**ViewModel:**

```
public void UpdateSelectedDevice()
{
    context.UpdateDevice(SelectedDevice);
}
```

**Business Context:**

```
public void UpdateDevice(Device device)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        InventoryTransaction it = GetLastestInventoryTransaction(device);
        it.DebitWipeOffDate = DateTime.Now;

        var entity = context.InventoryTransactions.Find(it.Id);
        context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(it);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Let's assume that we have two rows in the data grid. I change first row's attribute. And then I change the second row's one attribute, hit the save button.

What I'm expecting is as I'm selecting the second row, only second row's model is passing to `UpdateDevice()` function. So only second records is gets updated.

However even though I pass only specific model, after pressing button first row gets update too.

Comment: Show us your XAML and viewmodel as well.

Comment: both objects should be in the context, so SaveChanges() should save both rows back to the database. You could try setting the EntityState of the first object to Unchanged or use .AsNoTracking or disable ChangeTracking altogether.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro could you help me on how to do it? Do i need to set EntityState.Unchanged for all objects in the collection?

Comment: you have to set unchanged for all entities those changes you do not want to be reflected in the database. For those objects no update statements will be sent to the database, notice you may have FK incompabilities because of this (if you deleted the parent object, the whole transaction will throw an exception and be rolled back).